# Centos 6.6 Nautilus Context Menu has no Delete Function

Tags: centos, nautilus

For experimentation I installed Centos 6.6 in VM.
After install there is no delete function in nautilus file manager context menu. Is that expected behavior?

[image]

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: Looks like you just don't have the permissions to delete the folder...

Comment: Or... can [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/134859/cant-delete-a-file-with-nautilus-on-12-04-from-desktop) be of help?